# Emit handle in vue3?

Tags: vue.js, vue3

Как изменять пропсы через emit (vue3)
Child

```
 <template>
 <CaButton
    :background="isChoose ? '#2437DB' : '#EFF2F5'"
   @click="handleClickChoose"
   >
   <div>
      {{ title }}
  </div>
  <div v-if="isChoose" style="width: 9px; height: 9px;">
   <img :src="icon" alt="icon" >
  </div>
 </CaButton>
 </template>

<script>

export default {

   name: 'ButtonChip',

   props: {
   title: {
    type: String,
     default: '',
  },
    isChoose: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
    },
  },

 emits: ['myEvent'],

  methods: {
   handleClickChoose() {
   this.$emit('myEvent');
    },
  },

};
```

Parent

```
 <ButtonChip
  title="ass"
  @my-event="handleChoose"
>
</ButtonChip>
```

Comment: Ну можете записывать title в переменную вьюшную у родителя, а в `handleChoose` изменять.

Comment: Хотелось бы лучшое решения

Comment: Так это чуть ли не единственное решение.

Comment: Хорошо можно пример кодом, непонятно как-то